# I can't access my list(observable collection) from another class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a filtering using radio buttons and delegates. Basically I want to have a hard-coded list that would act like a pseudo database and then only display some items from the list depending on which button is pressed.

I have an `Apartment.cs` class that has a Name and ID property and nothing else.

Another class I have is `Apts.cs`:

```
public  class Apts
{
    private ObservableCollection<Apartment> apartments;
    public ObservableCollection<Apartment> Apartments { get; set; }


    public Apts()
    {
        apartments = new ObservableCollection<Apartment>()
        {
            new Apartment() {Name = "Name1", ID = 1},
            new Apartment() {Name = "Name2", ID = 2},
            new Apartment() {Name = "Name3", ID = 3},
        };
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the Apartments property which should be the list(am I wrong?) and pass it as a parameter to a `ListParis(ObservableCollection<Apartment>)` method I wrote. This code is in `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public void AssignDelegates()
{
    if (parisButton.IsPressed)
    {
        myFunc = DelActions.ListParis(Apartments);
    }
}
```

but I get an error saying:

```
CS0103  The name 'Apartments' does not exist in the current context
```

Why can't I access the list?

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of the code you are filling "apartments", the private one, while the public one is still empty. Then in the second potion of code you should initialize the class "Apt" in order to access to the public property Apartments. It should be like this:

```
myFunc = DelActions.ListParis(new Apts().Apartments);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should learn how to use properties.
[Using Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

You have to return your field inside your property getter, like this, so you can achieve what you want.

```
   public class Apts
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Apartment> apartments;
        public ObservableCollection<Apartment> Apartments
        {
            get
            {
                return apartments;
            }
            set
            {
                apartments = value;
            }
        }

        public Apts()
        {
            apartments = new ObservableCollection<Apartment>()
                {
                    new Apartment() {Name = "Name1", ID = 1},
                    new Apartment() {Name = "Name2", ID = 2},
                    new Apartment() {Name = "Name3", ID = 3},
                };
        }
    }
```

And second you have to initialize your "Apt" class to pass apartmets as parameter, like so:

```
public void AssignDelegates()
{
    if (parisButton.IsPressed)
    {
        Apts apartments = new Apts();
        myFunc = DelActions.ListParis(apartments.Apartments);
    }
}
```

Comment: I somehow forgot I need to initialize it o access the property. But I thought the syntax you used for the property and what I used are the same. Could you elaborate on the difference between the two?

Comment: Also, I'm getting this error: 

`CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DelegateTestUWP2.Apartment>' to 'System.Func<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DelegateTestUWP2.Apartment>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DelegateTestUWP2.Apartment>>' `

Comment: Message says it all, you are trying to pass parameter of type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Delegat‌​eTestUWP2.Apartment> but your method is expecting another ('System.Func<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollec‌​tion<DelegateTestUWP‌​2.Apartment>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DelegateTestUWP2.Apar‌​tment>>)

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. My method is returning ObservableCollection<Apartment> and the input is also ObservableCollection<Apartment>.